# Why SVM classifier generates bad results with LDA in Classification of audio data?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, pca, libsvm

I am using SVM classifier to classify my audio data (instrument strokes). I am using LDA as a feature reduction technique to reduce feature dimensions. After applying classifier the results I am getting is very low (only 45% accuracy). With the same data without any feature reduction and using PCA I am able to get more than 90% accuracy. What may be the problem?